# Looking for more simple LMS alternative to Moodle

Tags: web-apps, open-source, educational

I am looking for free and blind-friendly LMS for our non-profit organization. My needs are following:

1) database of students - not only current ones but possibly also potential one (for example they want to attend course but cannot attend on particular data/time) so I could write there contact details like email, phone, note (handicaps etc.)

2) course database - name, description, price

3) calendar - all courses, possibly course list not as grid but a simple list + registered students

3) course certificate printing - without added watermark (custom template if possible), we need to print certificates for accredited courses to help socially disadvantaged

4) document storage for courses, possibly also to be able to send them to the students (linking to other service could also be possible) (low priority)

5) printing other documents - for example attendance list of registered students for particular course if possible (low priority)

Already tried Moodle but it is really complicated for me (I am visually impaired) with plenty of menus and bad for orientation. Is there something better? Maybe something simple which can be expanded with modules or something else so we could have only the features we need.

Would be nice if the system could support also other languages than English (need Czech but some of my friends are able to translate it if needed).

Do you know a possible solution for my needs?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[eleapsoftware.com](http://www.eleapsoftware.com) does everything you specified as far as I know.

We use this LMS for training and the courses are purchased through the same platform, so I believe there is a way to distribute a course publicly (for a fee eventually).
I am not aware if their interface is visually impaired friendly.